# How to access a variable declared in the main activity in another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, global-variables

i don't know if this is possible or if they is a better programming practice but i'd like to know how to use a varible declared in the main activity in another activity. Source code snippet example is given like so...

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private int a, b;
private EditText first, second;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    first = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_entry);
    second = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.second_entry);   }

public void doMath(View view) throws Exception {
    try {
        if (!first.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            a = Integer.parseInt(first.getText().toString());
        }
        else {
            a = 0;
        }
        if (!second.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            b = Integer.parseInt(gpa_credits1.getText().toString());
        }
        else {
            b = 0;
        }

        int sum = a + b;    }catch (Exception e) {}
```

now, i would like to create a new activity to use the variable "sum" to do some math like...

```
public class first_year_second_semester extends Activity {


 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newActivity);
    int blah = 5;
    private TextView soln;
    soln = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.the_soln);
    soln = (blah / sum) //i.e sum from the previous activity...please i need this
}
```

Comment: Where do you start "first_year_second_semester" activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the value from one to other activity using intent or using shared preferences.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,year_second_semester.class);
intent.putExtras("sum",sum);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in next activity you can get this value.

Or using shared preferences:
Inside class:
        SharedPreferences shared;

Inside onCreate:
          shared=getSharedPreferences("app",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

After computing the sum I.e. after doing sum=a+b;

```
Editor edit=shared.edit();
edit.putString("sum",sum);
edit.commit();
```

And in the next activity:
Inside the class:
    SharedPreferences shared;

Inside oncreate:
        shared=getSharedPreferences("app",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Wherver you want:
    String yourvalue=shared.getString("sum","default value");

Here your value will be the sum from the main activity.

Comment: okay @user3541465 i'll try it. but do i just paste your code in the onCreate method or where? and why the usage of String here... pardon a newbie.

Comment: You can also use int like : shared.putInt("sum",sum);   and when getting the value you have to use : shared.getInt("sum",0);  where 0 is the default value, you can pass any default value in place of 0.

Answer (score 3):

Create a public static variable in your main activity (where the do math method is) like so:

```
public static int SUM;
```

Then in the do math function set that value to the one calculated.

```
int sum = a+b;
SUM = sum;
```

Then you can access it via:

```
MainActivity.SUM
```

Comment: What about intent extras ?

Comment: That could be done too but I don't know if the MainActivity is launching the other activity.

Comment: so in the newActivity, i will just use it as { soln = (blah / MainActivity.SUM) } ?

Comment: And also you can't set an int to a text field. Use `soln.setText(blah / MainActivity.SUM)`